# Using Chart.js on Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

I'm going to use chart using chart.js on my laravel project. I've tried but the chart didn't show.

This is my controller (HomeController.php)

```
public function chartData()
{
    $pemesanan = DetailPemesanan::join('pemesanan', 'detail_pemesanan.id_pemesanan', '=', 'pemesanan.id_pemesanan')
        ->select('pemesanan.tgl_pesan as tgl_pesan', DB::raw('SUM(detail_pemesanan.jumlah) as jumlah'))
        ->where('tgl_pesan', '>=', 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 DAY))')
        ->groupBy('pemesanan.tgl_pesan')
        ->get();
    return $pemesanan;
}
```

This is my view

```
<div class="col-md-9">
     <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
@section('script')
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.getJSON("/chart-data", function (result) {

            var labels = [],data=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                labels.push(result[i].tgl_pesan);
                data.push(result[i].jumlah);
            }

            var transaksiData = {
                labels : labels,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor : "rgba(240, 127, 110, 0.3)",
                        strokeColor : "#f56954",
                        pointColor : "#A62121",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#741F1F",
                        data : data
                    }
                ]
            };
            var transaksi = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

            new Chart(transaksi).Line(transaksiData, {
                bezierCurve : true
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@endsection
```

And this is my route

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/chart-data', 'HomeController@chartData');
```

Anyone know what should I do? Big Thanks

Comment: just to be sure, have you `dd` the `$pemesanan` first? how does the output looked like? also, i'm a bit bothered by `return $pemesanan;`, i believe you should do `return $pemesanan->toJson();`. [here is the docs for toJson](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_toJson). Cheers, and happy coding~

Comment: no, it didn't show anything when I `dd($pemesanan)`

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I figured out that I'm using the version 2.x of chart.js and I've changed this

```
new Chart(transaksi).Line(transaksiData, {
    bezierCurve : true
});
```

into this

```
var chartInstance = new Chart(transaksi, {
    type: 'line',
    data: transaksiData,
});
```